# AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'core'

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

I have installed the tensorflow library on Windows, then my Pandas library stopped working, and after pandas importing appears the same issue as by importing the tensorflow.

```
import pandas as pd
```

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-af55e7023913> in <module>()
----> 1 import pandas as pd

C:\Users\kozyr\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in <module>()
     40 import pandas.core.config_init
     41 
---> 42 from pandas.core.api import *
     43 from pandas.core.sparse.api import *
     44 from pandas.stats.api import *

C:\Users\kozyr\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py in <module>()
      8 from pandas.core.dtypes.missing import isnull, notnull
      9 from pandas.core.categorical import Categorical
---> 10 from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper
     11 from pandas.io.formats.format import set_eng_float_format
     12 from pandas.core.index import (Index, CategoricalIndex, Int64Index,

C:\Users\kozyr\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py in <module>()
     47                                CategoricalIndex, _ensure_index)
     48 from pandas.core.categorical import Categorical
---> 49 from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
     50 from pandas.core.generic import NDFrame, _shared_docs
     51 from pandas.core.internals import BlockManager, make_block

C:\Users\kozyr\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in <module>()
     65                                 _maybe_box_datetimelike,
     66                                 _dict_compat)
---> 67 from pandas.core.generic import NDFrame, _shared_docs
     68 from pandas.core.index import Index, MultiIndex, _ensure_index
     69 from pandas.core.indexing import (maybe_droplevels, convert_to_index_sliceable,

C:\Users\kozyr\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in <module>()
     39 from pandas.core.index import (Index, MultiIndex, _ensure_index,
     40                                InvalidIndexError)
---> 41 import pandas.core.indexing as indexing
     42 from pandas.core.indexes.datetimes import DatetimeIndex
     43 from pandas.core.indexes.period import PeriodIndex, Period

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'core'
```

Tried to re-installed pandas and TensorFlow, but nothing helped.

Comment: Did you install numpy?

Answer (score 13):

I have just encountered this problem and solved it. This is my solution way:
use `conda upgrade --all` and then restart you notebook.

Answer (score 7):

Use older version of pandas: `pip install pandas==0.22`

Comment: I don't know why this answer has negative votes. I tried all the above answers, but only this worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I had pandas version 0.25 in Ubuntu 19.04, but for work this library
I returned pandas from 0.25 version to 0.24.

```
pip install pandas==0.24
```

(python 3.6)

Comment: note : it was giving this error in kubernetis airflow environment ... **apache-airflow 2.1.4 requires markupsafe<2.0,>=1.1.1, but you have markupsafe 2.0.1 which is incompatible.**

Answer (score 2):

1) import it again and then

2) update your Bash profile , and you will not see this error after that and then

3) restart your notebook , hope it helps

Comment: What do you mean by "update your Bash profile"? Without this information, the answer is useless IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I tried both upgrading conda and restarting jupyter notebook/ uninstall pandas and reinstall pandas. It worked

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar error when importing `pandas.core.config`. It returned

```
AttributeError: module 'pandas.core' has no attribute 'config'
```

The error disappears when I uninstall current version (1.1.2) and re-install pandas in older version (0.22).
It seems like the error had happened since v0.25 according to this [issue thread](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/27471).

Answer (score 0):

in Colab helped in top_right area Arrow-Down => Disconnect and delete runtime